# Linking to a dynamic library on a Mac with full path

Tags: macos, linker, dylib

I am linking a (Python extension) library that embeds the Matlab engine with the following command (generated using cmake)

```
c++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -bundle -headerpad_max_install_names  -o library.so library.o /Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/bin/maci64/libeng.dylib /Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/bin/maci64/libmx.dylib -framework Python
```

resulting in

```
$ otool -L library.so
library.so:
    @loader_path/libeng.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @loader_path/libmx.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python (compatibility version 2.6.0, current version 2.6.1)
    /opt/local/lib/gcc44/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.13.0)
    /opt/local/lib/gcc44/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.0)
```

However, when I try to use the library, I get an error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(./library.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib
  Referenced from: ./library.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I believe the problem stems from the fact that the linker includes the matlab dylib files in the form `@loader_path/libeng.dylib` rather than using the full path, even though I give the full path to `g++`. How can I force the linker to use the full path?

I know one solution is to use

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/bin/maci64:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

which is where those library files reside, but I'd like to avoid that as it causes some other problems.

Comment: Please refer my answer in this link 

[Add_libray][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876740/xcode-keeps-searching-dylib-at-wrong-path/19245310#19245310

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Manually changing the files using `install_name_tool`

```
install_name_tool -change "@loader_path/libeng.dylib" "/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/bin/maci64/libeng.dylib" library.so 
install_name_tool -change "@loader_path/libmx.dylib" "/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/bin/maci64/libmx.dylib" library.so
```

I could use this as a temporary fix, but I wonder if there isn't a better solution where the linker is given a setting to use the full paths.

Comment: this is useful, but you're right, there should be a way of doing this in CMake

Comment: I ended up needing to do the inverse operation; replacing an absolute path with one involving `@loader_path`. The [dyld man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) was helpful in explaining the behaviour of dyld as it regards absolute paths and expansion of `@loader_path`.

Comment: the thing with the install_name_tool is that it doesn't work as expected if the library is code signed, right?

Answer (score 7):

Note that some of the problems with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` can be prevented by using `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` instead. This will only be used if the lib cannot be found in the default paths.

Comment: Using this just broke the shell I was in, and gave me:
```
 python
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libpython2.7.dylib
  Referenced from: .../bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

```

Answer (score 5):

Look into the -rpath option to the ld command to control this. You might also be interested in the contents of https://github.com/bimargulies/jni-origin-testbed, which is a demonstration of some relevant technology.

The critical technique here is:

```
install_name_tool -change libsl2.so "@loader_path/libsl2.so" libsl1.so
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this? I'm having same issue. I feel like a few of the paths in my built project are not looking to the correct place!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use symbolic link !