# Xcode keeps searching dylib at wrong path

Tags: xcode, linker, dylib

Thats my error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libofa.0.dylib
Referenced from: /sers/david/Projekte/Test/build/Debug/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test
Reason: image not found
```

I've done some research and changed the path inside the dylib with install_name_tool:

```
davids-macbook:Test david$ otool -L libofa.0.0.0.dylib 
libofa.0.0.0.dylib:
@executable_path/../Frameworks/libofa.0.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
```

But Xcode keeps searching for it in /usr/lib/:

```
build/Debug/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 15.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/TagLib.framework/Versions/A/TagLib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.2.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Quartz (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libofa.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 103.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 227.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 44.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 550.29.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 751.29.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1038.32.0)
```

Is there a way to set this in Xcode??? Thanks

**Edit:** The library is not a Xcode project. Its build with ./configure; make

Comment: Xcode doesn't, the linker does.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Xcode to tell the linker..?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Normally what I do is this:

1. Set the **Installation Directory** of the library to *`@rpath`*. This will set the install name to `@rpath/libofa.0.0.0.dylib`. If you're building the library yourself, you can set this in Xcode; otherwise, use `install_name_tool` to change it.
2. Set the **Runpath Search Paths** of the application using the library to the location of the directory containing the library. For example, if you put the library in the app's Frameworks directory, you'd set **Runpath Search Paths** to *`@executable_path/../Frameworks`* (or *`@loader_path/../Frameworks`*).

[This blog post](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/) and [this one](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) go into more detail.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Still my error persists.
I've set the the path with install_name_tool -id. I tried install-name_tool -add_rpath. nothing works. 
I tried setting the Runpath Search Paths and the Runtime Search Paths to @loader_path/../Frameworks
Still its "dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libofa.0.dylib"

Comment: Stupid me. I had some stupid include settings in my project. Thanks!

Comment: Hi david, I have the same problem and cannot find out what you mean with 'stupid include settings'. Can you give a short example?

Comment: Same, also having this problem and NO solution on google has told me how to fix it

Comment: how do you set the "Installation Directory of a library" using install_name_tool ? none of its options relates to "Installation Directory" ???

Comment: @MottiShneor: It's the `-id` option.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. now "id" stands for "Installation Directory" and not just... well... id? Fun with Apple.

Comment: @MottiShneor: No, it's short for "identification name", as noted in the man page.

Comment: This fixed it!  For the **pre-built** framework PGSQLKit in my OS X app, I had to add a build phase script `install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/PGSQLKit.framework/PGSQLKit "$SRCROOT/PGSQLKit.framework/PGSQLKit"` (substitute your framework's name accordingly). Also, note that I also had to remove runpath search paths other than `@executable_path/../Frameworks` before it finally worked.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure to install the command line tools from developer.apple.com and then add the library in your project. Run the following script in your Xcode: *Targets » Build Phases » Run Script* and just execute:

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/librayName.dylib "$SRCROOT/librayName.dylib"
```

Note: NO ' or "" required before dylib name

Comment: Great tip! By the way, for frameworks, use `install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework "$SRCROOT/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework"` (where `MyFramework` is the framework's name) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Before going for solution, you should know what is new with dependent library "dylib" in MAC as compare to dependent library "dll" in windows.

The major difference in dylib vs dll is "install name". The install name is a path baked into the dynamic library that says where to find the library at runtime. It does not matter where you copy your dylibs, It will always point to old path(except without changing install name).
You can know original search path(install name) by using command as below

`otool -L a.dylib`

(just drag dylib in place of a.dylib)

For more detail about install name, refer this [link](http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/4235/how-to-distribute-a-dylib-with-a-mac-os-x-application).

Now, solution for changing the new location for dylib("install name") is just use `install_name_tool` as below

`install_name_tool -change *old path of dylb* *new path of dylib*`

you can get old path by `otool -L` command described above already.(old path i.e.  original path)

`install_name_tool -change` can change search path of dylib and executable as well.

You can use this in Xcode by writing in `Run script` file in your project.