# dylib missing on iOS application

Tags: ios, opencv, linker, xcode6

I am trying to port a program made using OpenCV 2.4 (not 3) from OSX to iOS 7 (not 8, or 9)

I followed their tutorial, that worked until it complained of jpeg linking errors, I pasted the errors on google, and found on their issue tracker a solution, and a link to the jpeg library, I downloaded it, did all the steps correctly, and now it compiles and runs, but crashes on startup and complains with the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib/libjpeg.62.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876740/xcode-keeps-searching-dylib-at-wrong-path

Comment: This applies more to OSX than iOS

Answer (score 3):

Go to your *Project* -> *Target* -> *General* -> *Linked Frameworks and Libraries* and try changing the status of the **libjpeg.a** library you linked to "**Optional**" instead of "**Required**".

I was having the same exact issue and changing the status fixed the crash for me.  Not sure why.

Comment: It doesn't solve problem - it just doesn't kill process on dylib loading failure but still doesn't load dylib