# pygame py2app Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib

Tags: pygame, importerror, dylib, dlopen, py2app

I wouldn't call myself a programmer and am unfamiliar with Mac and Linux, so any links or pointers to additional background would help greatly.  I've started with the most basic pygame I could google, (from https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/).  The test.py and test.app runs on my VM but not on anyone else's real Macs.

---

### test.py file

```
import pygame

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
    done = False

    while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            done = True

            pygame.display.flip()
```

---

### setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['test.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

---

### command to create the test.app

$ python3 setup.py py2app

---

The test.app runs fine on the VM, but whenever the test.app runs on a real Mac (tested 2, one ran on Catalina ver???) this error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 101, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Applications/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Applications/test.app/Contents/Resources/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "pygame/__init__.pyc", line 120, in <module>
  File "pygame/base.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "pygame/base.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/test.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/pygame/base.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/test.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/pygame/base.so
  Reason: image not found
2020-05-02 11:27:50.309 test[931:15836] test Error

----------------------------
Working environment: VirtualBox 6.1, macOS Sierra (Version 10.12) with the following:

$ pip list

Package     Version
----------- ----------
altgraph    0.17
certifi     2020.4.5.1
macholib    1.14
modulegraph 0.18
pip         20.1
py2app      0.21
pygame      1.9.6
setuptools  39.0.1
wheel       0.34.2

$ brew list --versions

freetype 2.10.1
gdbm 1.18.1
jpeg 9d
libmikmod 3.3.11.1
libogg 1.3.4
libpng 1.6.37
libtiff 4.1.0
libvorbis 1.3.6
openssl@1.1 1.1.1g
pkg-config 0.29.2_3
python 3.7.7
readline 8.0.4
sdl 1.2.15_1
sdl2 2.0.12_1
sdl_image 1.2.12_7
sdl_mixer 1.2.12_3
sdl_ttf 2.0.11_1
sqlite 3.31.1
webp 1.1.0
xz 5.2.5
```

---

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated. The actual program is an OhHell card game which supports Windows clients (via pyinstaller), but I'm also trying to support a Mac client to play with my friends on a Mac.  Similar to the test.py and test.app (ohhell.py and ohhell.app) runs on the VM Mac but same issue/error occurs with real macs.  I've just included the simplest code snippet that I was able to google that reproduced the exact error message.

-john

Comment: I guess a few more useful comments: 1) /test.app/Contents/Frameworks/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib does exist 2) the libSDL-1.2.0.dylib did not exist on the real mac that it failed (outside the test.app package itself) 3) I tried including that dylib in the setup_test.py DATA_FILES

Comment: I updated to the latest setuptools (setuptools-46.1.3), but still get the with same message.

Comment: It appears the application runs on a real Mac provided the following .dylib files are installed separately (was installed and removed via brew).  It cannot reference them on the App Package Contents: sdl 1.2.15_1 (base.so error), sdl_mixer 1.2.12_3 (mixer.so error), sdl_ttf 2.0.11_1 (font.so error)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround Solution: [Linking to a dynamic library on a Mac with full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937232/linking-to-a-dynamic-library-on-a-mac-with-full-path) and [What path does @loader_path resolve to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826922/what-path-does-loader-path-resolve-to). Using the '$ install_name_tool -change "@loader_path/.dylibs/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib" "/Applications/test.app/Contents/Frameworks/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib" base.so' resolved the Library not loaded: loader_path/.dylibs/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib errors.  I assume this hard codes the path, but with my friends it's fine to tell them to make sure it resides in the /Applications folder.

However a secondary problem came up, 'pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file'. I used py2app, so the pygame delete and reinstall threads didn't seem like a feasible solution (pygame unnecesary w/py2app), so switching the images to uncompressed bitmap (256 colors) worked.

For those curious, I did try Pyinstaller for Mac but that presented a whole new set of problems.