# C/MATLAB API interface environment variable settings affects other applications in OS X

Tags: c++, matlab, environment-variables, openmp

I'm calling MATLAB from my c++ code via the MATLAB Engine API library on a Mac. I learned that I need to set the environment variable:

```
export PATH='/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin:$PATH'
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/sys/os/maci64:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

then I was able to setup the Matlab engine running. However I realised the setting of those environment variables have other effects: within the shell, curl stops working. What's worse is that some multi-threaded codes compiled by openmp stop working as well. I hope to find an alternative way of setting the environment for Matlab API, without disrupting other applications. Thanks.

Comment: try putting those in `""` not in  `  ` - that could be the case in Linux. Maybe the same is on your osx

Comment: @DawidPi, does not affect anything. I guess in OS X shell, single or double quotes both work.

Comment: nobody answers my question.......

Comment: maybe noone knows the answer... Do not be mad :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a few solutions here.
[Linking to a dynamic library on a Mac with full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937232/linking-to-a-dynamic-library-on-a-mac-with-full-path)

In particular I like quazgar's answer the best. When a program looking for a library path in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH fails to find the needed library, the program will look into the environment variable DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH if there is such a variable.

The solution is to change DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH instead of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. Change of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not recommended in any circumstances, as it will creates lots of trouble for the environment.