# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libeng.dylib

Tags: c++, macos, g++, shared-libraries, matlab-engine

I am trying to use the MATLAB Engine to invoke some MATLAB functions from C++ on MAC-OSX El Capitán. I've seen similar posts but none of them explains the situation calmly in a way that unprofessional people might understand. Can someone give me an simple explanation and easy fix?

I get the following error message at **runtime**:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libeng.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Admin/Desktop/cpp_to_matlab/./engdemo
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: You need a copy of `libeng.dylib` in the same directory as the program `engdemo`. I'm guessing that `libeng.dylib` is some matlab library. TBH you need to show the compilation error that's indicating this issue; as that error pretty much only shows up at run-time.

Comment: When you compile?  Not when you run the executable? Use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12522096/299924) to show us the runpath of the executable (update your question).

Comment: @trojanfoe The problem happens at execution time. The compilation is completed without complaints. Also I tried to run both "otool -1" after the execution and "otool -1 engdemo" before that but I don't get any runpath description. How should I run this routine?

Comment: @Petesh That didn't do...

Comment: @AlexisRustamDevitre That's `-l` not `-1`.

Comment: @AlexisRustamDevitre Check solutions from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937232/linking-to-a-dynamic-library-on-a-mac-with-full-path). The issue seems to point at relative vs. absolute paths problem.

Comment: @trojanfoe hahahaha....yeah clearly it's -l... I feel so dumb haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100900-how-to-run-engdemo-cpp-in-mac-10-8-mountain-lion-in-matlab-r2013a). I was missing a whole bunch of libraries, but somehow the compiler/runtime never said anything about those...